# Detrending DTMs

Tags: qgis, dem

I've been using the method for detrending DTMs given here (in Clause 10.3):

[BAJR](http://www.bajr.org/BAJRGuides/42_QGIS_StarterGuide/42_BAJR_Guide_QGIS.pdf)

The results are encouraging but I'd like to 'flatten' the underlying terrain even more.

One of my DTMs has elevations of  between about 60 m and 136 m and the area of coverage is about 4000 m by 2500 m.

My question is about the 'Radius' I should set in the SAGA Simple filter algorithm  to obtain optimum results. The BAJR guide suggests '6' for 0.25 m DTMs, '12' for 0.50 m DTMs and '25' for 1.0 m DTMs. For the 2 m DTM I've been using I applied a value of 50.

What would be a reasonable radius value to use to 'flatten' the underlying terrain still further?